# Will HTTPS encrypt Blazor WebAssembly API calls once published to Azure?

Tags: c#, https, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am working with a Blazor Web Assembly project targeting .NET 6.0 equipped with a ASP.NET Core hosted server. While in development on Google Chrome, I can press F12 and go to the Network tab to see the API calls being made. In each call I can see the data that is being transferred. Because this data is sensitive, my question is if I were to push this to Azure, would HTTPS encrypt these API calls or are there more steps I need take to secure this?

The Program.cs file in the server project has this line: app.UseHttpsRedirection();

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, if you are using HTTPS, the data transferred is encrypted by the server and then decrypted by the client. When you go to network on your browser, the data you are seeing has already been decrypted.

Comment: Interesting question and HTTPS will encrypt data for transport, but once its on your client side that has the correct decryption key, the payload can be read in the network tab. If what you need is that data to be obfuscated, then it is not the SSL you need. 

I am curious to see what can do that

Comment: "In each call I can see the data that is being transferred" you can't hide things from the browser itself nor from the user who is using it

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I believe I understand the process more clear now. I am simply returning something from the API call that should not be returned. Thanks again.